# By convention, when observing an exoplanet, is the observer's line of sight (on Earth) perpendicular to the plane of sky?

Tags: orbit, astrophysics, exoplanet, binary-star

This is just a quick question. In this [picture of the orbit of an exoplanet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_periapsis#/media/File:Orbit1.svg), is the observer's line of sight perpendicular to the plane of reference, which is in the +z direction on the diagram? In the case when the inclination equals to $90^{\circ}$, it is ideal for us to measure the radial velocity. Is that right?

Comment: That is not a picture of the orbit of an exoplanet. That is a diagram showing the meaning of various orbital elements.

Comment: @James K  But when studying an exoplanet orbiting its host star, the diagram is similar to this. There's not too much difference right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reference plane for exoplanet [orbital inclination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_inclination#Exoplanets_and_multiple_star_systems) is our sky plane.
From the NASA Exoplanet Archive [documentation](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/parhelp.html#i-l):

> The Observed Inclination is the orbital inclination with respect to the plane of the sky....
>   0 degrees correspond to an orbit in the plane of the sky, face on with respect to our line of sight.
>   90 degrees corresponds to an orbit that is edge-on with respect to our line of sight, perpendicular to the plane of the sky.

If you [query the archive](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=planets) for exoplanets with discovery method "Transit," you get inclinations mostly between 85° and 90°.

If the only available observation is a fluctuation in the star's radial velocity, then the planet's mass ***m*** and orbital inclination ***i*** are unknown, but a [minimum mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mass) ***m* sin *i*** can be computed.
The actual mass is greater unless ***i*** = 90°.

The orbit diagram from Wikipedia can apply to extrasolar systems with one change: the reference direction is celestial north instead of ♈.